# Should we eliminate the translation in other languages ​​that may not be necessary?

Tags: discussion, policy

Please see the edit history of this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/61459/9467) first.

Without intending to insult other languages, should we eliminate the translation in other languages ​​that may not be necessary?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Considering [the community opinion (link)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/693/11002), I think that the site should be kept as English-only as possible. Conclusion: The moderator edit was correct IMO and the answer should be exclusively English.

Answer (score 17):

[ar] وأعتقد أننا ينبغي أن تكون مفتوحة قدر الإمكان. على وجه الخصوص هذه المناقشة يجب أن تكون متاحة للمتحدثين من جميع اللغات.

[ca] Crec que hem de ser el més obert possible. En particular, aquest debat ha de ser accessible per als parlants de qualsevol llengua.

[cy] Yr wyf yn meddwl y dylem fod mor agored â phosibl. Yn arbennig y drafodaeth hon mae angen i fod yn hygyrch i siaradwyr pob iaith.

[de] Ich denke, wir sollten so offen wie möglich sein. Insbesondere sollte diese Diskussion für Sprecher aller Sprachen zugänglich sein.

[el] Νομίζω ότι πρέπει να είναι όσο το δυνατόν πιο ανοικτή. Ειδικότερα, η συζήτηση αυτή πρέπει να είναι προσπελάσιμες για τους ομιλητές όλων των γλωσσών.

[en] I think we should be as open as possible. In particular this discussion needs to be accessible for speakers of all languages.

[eo] Mi kredas ke ni devus esti kiel malfermita ebla. En aparta ĉi diskuto bezonas esti alirebla por parolantoj de ĉiuj lingvoj.

[es] Creo que debemos ser lo más abierto posible. En particular, este debate tiene que ser accesible para los hablantes de cualquier lengua.

[fa] من فکر می کنم که ممکن است ما باید به عنوان باز. به خصوص این بحث باید برای سخنرانان از همه زبانها در دسترس است.

[fi] Mielestäni meidän pitäisi olla mahdollisimman avoimia. Erityisesti tässä keskustelussa on oltava saatavilla kaikkien kielten puhujien.

[fr] Je pense que nous devrions être aussi ouvert que possible. En particulier, cette discussion doit être accessible pour les locuteurs de toutes les langues.

[he] אני חושב שאנחנו צריכים להיות פתוחים ככל האפשר. בפרט הדיון הזה צריך להיות נגיש עבור דוברי השפות.

[hi] मुझे लगता है कि हम के रूप में संभव के रूप में खुला होना चाहिए. विशेष रूप में इस चर्चा के लिए सभी भाषाओं के बोलने वालों के लिए सुलभ हो की जरूरत है.

[ht] Mwen panse ke nou ta dwe kòm louvri ke posib. An patikilye sa a diskisyon bezwen aksesib pou moun ki pale tout lang.

[is] Ég held að við ættum að vera eins opinn og mögulegt er. Þetta á sérstaklega við umfjöllun þarf að vera aðgengileg fyrir hátalarana á öllum tungumálum.

[it] Penso che dovremmo essere il più trasparenti possibile. In particolare, questa discussione deve essere accessibile per i parlanti di tutte le lingue.

[ja] 私たちは可能な限りオープンであるべきだと思います。特に、この議論は、すべての言語の話者のためにアクセスする必要があります。

[ko] 나는 우리가 최대한 공개해야한다고 생각. 특히이 토론은 모든 언어의 스피커에 대한 접근이 있어야합니다.

[la] Sicut patet maxime puto. In particulari hoc disputatione indiget ad esse pervia enim disertis omnes linguis.

[nl] Ik denk dat we zo open mogelijk te zijn. In het bijzonder, moet deze discussie toegankelijk voor sprekers van alle talen zijn.

[pl] Myślę, że powinniśmy być jak najbardziej otwarte. W szczególności ta dyskusja musi być dostępne dla mówiących różnymi językami.

[ptb] Acredito que devamos operar da forma mais aberta possível. Em particular, esta discussão precisa estar acessível a quem fala qualquer idioma.

[ru] Я думаю, что мы должны быть максимально открытыми. В частности, эта дискуссия должна быть доступной для говорящих на всех языках.

[ta] நான் நாம் முடிந்தவரை திறந்த இருக்கவேண்டும் என்று நான் நினைக்கிறேன். குறிப்பாக இந்த விவாதம் அனைத்து மொழிகளின் பேச்சாளர்கள் அணுகவேண்டும் இருக்க வேண்டும்.

[te] నేను మేము వీలైనంత ఓపెన్ ఉండాలి అనుకుంటున్నాను. ముఖ్యంగా ఈ చర్చ అన్ని భాషలు మాట్లాడేవారు అందుబాటులో ఉండాలి.

[th] ผมคิดว่าเราควรจะเป็นเปิดเป็นไปได้ โดยเฉพาะอย่างยิ่งการอภิปรายนี้จะต้องสามารถเข้าถึงได้สำหรับลำโพงของทุกภาษา

[tr] Olabildiğince açık olmamız gerektiğini düşünüyorum. Özellikle bu tartışmanın diğer dilleri konuşan tüm insanlar için erişilebilir olması gerekiyor.

[zh] 我认为我们应该尽可能开放。特别是这次讨论需要访问所有语言的扬声器。

[may] Saya fikir kita harus seterbuka mungkin. Secara khusus, perbincangan ini perlu boleh diakses untuk penutur semua bahasa.

(My apologies to speakers of the ~3000-6000 languages that I left out or that Google translate doesn't know. Also apologies for any horrible translations. Please improve and add translations.)

---

Seriously though, without proper software support, multilingual posts add a lot of clutter to the site. The SE approach partially works because they distilled Q&A down to the essentials, so that information is easy to find. Doubling (tripling, ...) post length makes it a lot harder to find what one is looking for and will also make it less likely that someone reads the question/answer.

Comment: I'll give you a 50 rep bounty if you typeset that in LaTeX.

Comment: @doncherry: Not too hard with lua/xelatex. You only need to find the appropriate fonts.

Comment: @doncherry: There are no bounties on meta ;-)

Comment: Jeg blir litt overraskelt at Google Translate ikke kjenner norsk.

Comment: @AndrewStacey Es kennt Norwegisch (und bessert sogar den Tippfehler aus).  Aber ich war zu faul alle 64 Sprachen die Google Translate momentan anbietet zu verwenden.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: I have offered a bounty on meta, see [:-)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/133507/186526)

Comment: @HiggsBoson: Sorry, no I don't see any bounty nor any button which would allow me to offer one. You can't own rep on meta anyway, so it makes sense.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: It means that the bounty might be disabled on meta.tex.se but not for all  meta.<something>.se sites. :-)

Comment: @HiggsBoson/Forgiver/... : As far as I know, they are *only* available on Meta.SO (the only meta site that has independent reputation).

Comment: @Caramdir/Clemens Koppensteiner: OK. Thanks.

Comment: @TomBombadil: Mutig!

Comment: @mhp: Danke! Obwohl ich mit zweimal "sollte... sein" immer noch nicht allzu glücklich bin :(

Comment: [I would like to buy a hamburger](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iUCDhvbQFmU). `:)`

Comment: [A... a... a..., you are cheating yourself](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sQVgniNcO_g). :-)

Answer (score 4):

Proposal, describing four cases and how to treat them:

1. **Answer in English only:**
   necessary and sufficient.
2. **Answer in English plus, *within the same answer*, some French (f.ex.):**
   Feel free. Nothing wrong with improving findability, cross-lingual included. (When I say 'some', I'm thinking of French keywords, or a French copy of a sentence, or even a complete translation.)
3. **Answer in mixed French and English:** No, that's only useful to us bilinguals.
4. **One answer in French, one answer in English, both describing the same thing:**
   No, let's try to keep everything in one answer. (One answer per solution, one solution per answer.)
5. **Answer only in French:** unfortunately not.

When one encouters case 3 or 4 or 5 one can edit and/or ask the author/anyone for a translation, whatever means of feedback is one's personal style, to indicate that answers on this site should be in English at least. If nobody bothers to translate it and the answer remains in not-English, it's probably best to flag it for deletion as "not welcome in our community".

Perhaps there can be a tex-fr.se sister site, but I don't think it's a good idea to mix languages within one site — it'll lead to too much noise for everybody but the bilinguals among us.

Comment: I think that downloading should be related to the contents and not to the language. Answer in other language is to be (1) asked the owner to translate it if he's able to; (2) translated if there's someone else able and willing to do it; or (3) flagged for deletion.

Comment: Good idea. Answer edited accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

[fr] ne peut-on pas imaginer que le forum soit le plus ouvert possible, je trouve que ma manière de procéder permet de [langue originale]  et [english]  permet de faire progresser aussi bien les utilisateurs anglais, que le reste du monde et améliore les recherches en langue étrangère avec Google

[en] can we not imagine that the forum is as open as possible, I find my own way of proceeding allows [original language] and [english] will advance both English users, the rest of the world and improves research in a foreign language with Google

[fr] maintenant si vous pensez que mes commentaires doivent être effacés, faites donc. Moi je continuerai à répondre aux questions

[en] Now if you think my comments should be deleted so do it. I shall continue to answer.

Comment: -1: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/2573/4012. "Being as open as possible" as you imagine it is not a goal of Stack Exchange and won't work imho.

Comment: It's unfortunately not possible to be effectively multilingual on this site.  It's also true that using English can limit participation and usage of the site, but I see no real alternative than creating specialized sites or forums in the various languages, where people who understand English can use this and other sites when giving answers. I surely hope you'll continue to give your contribution here.

Comment: If you want to read this site in French and you use Google Translate for it, I think you can get Google Translate add-on for most of the web browsers.