# What is the simplest way to copy the url of a comment?

Tags: support, comments, hyperlinks

Visiting a user activity page and right-clicking the corresponding comment hyperlink to copy the url seem to be cumbersome.

Is there the simplest way to do it?

Of course, there will not be a permanent link because the user can delete his/her comment later.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Right-click the time stamp of the comment and select "copy link URL" (or the like):

[image: screen shot]

<sub>(Could someone provide screen shots in the rest of the languages, in order to comply with our new [*all languages* policy](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2594/4012)? `;)`)</sub>

English by the God Particle:

[image: English screen shot]

Comment: This is an example.

Comment: It is a hidden feature that almost nobody knows (i think).

Comment: I cannot edit your answer, then I put the image on my question. Please kindly take it and don't leave traces.  Thanks. :-)

Comment: @HiggsBoson: Done already. But you should be able to suggest edits on meta as well? (Regardless of the fact that you'll break the 2k barrier soon.)

Comment: There is no edit button shown in your answer. I can only see link and flag buttons. Maybe I will see the edit button later.

Comment: @HiggsBoson: Strange. Looking at http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/81701/162565, I could only see #1 or #4 applying here? What happens when you go to http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/posts/2603/edit?

Comment: "There is a pending suggested edit in the queue, try again in a few minutes." for the last link.

Comment: @HiggsBoson: Seems buggy to me, you might wanna check [meta.se] and perhaps post a bug report there.

Comment: Visiting [meta.tex.stackexchange.com/posts/2603/edit](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/posts/2603) produces "404 error" but visting [meta.tex.stackexchange.com/posts/2603/edit](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/posts/2603/edit) produces "There is a pending suggested edit in the queue, try again in a few minutes." Is it enough  to inform the bug?

Comment: I have submitted a bug report [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/138879/186526).

Comment: I can see the edit button now.

Comment: @HiggsBoson: Yes, because you're >2k rep. Beforehand, you couldn't because suggested edits are turned off on per-site metas. Your meta.so question can probably be resolved, perhaps you could answer Shog9 at http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/138888/162565?